# Lodash _.set only if object exists

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am looking to set inner properties of an object only if they already exist. Lodash `_.set` will create the whole hierarchy if it does not exist.

Is there an easy way to do this ? (Without and if statement ?)

Snippet below:

```js
const obj = {a: {b: 1}};

_.set(obj, 'a.b', 2);

console.log(obj); // Great !

_.set(obj, 'a.c', 1);

console.log(obj); // Great but not what I want. I would like c not to be set because it does not exist in the first place
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check it with `_.has` first?

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#has

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from Kalaiselvan A below put me on the way but this is not quite what I was looking for.

Using the same idea but improving the ternary gives me the following solution which I am happy with.

```js
const obj = {a: {b: 1}};

_.has(obj, 'a.b') && _.set(obj, 'a.b', 2);

console.log(obj);

_.has(obj, 'a.c') && _.set(obj, 'a.c', 2);

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cool but it does traverse the object in earch of "a.b" twice. Definitely not an issue for short paths, but as soon as you do this too often it might get slow.

Answer (score 3):

you can try by this way

```js
const obj = {a: {b: 1}};

_.set(obj, 'a.b', 2);

console.log(obj); // Great !
_.has(obj,'a.c')==true?_.set(obj, 'a.c', 1):""

console.log(obj); // Great but not what I want. I would like c not to be set because it does not exist in the first place
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: great, but breaks the OP's self imposed restriction `Without and[sic] if statement`

Comment: @JaromandaX I personally believe that unless an OP justifies that requirement - it may safely be ignored. I bet something like "it's not functional" would come.

Comment: I wasn't criticising the answer :p

Comment: @JaromandaX and see the edit! If being pedantic - Kalaiselvan A solved it without `if` statement :-D So, totally a +1 from me

Comment: @JaromandaX  sorry I didn't notice that `without If`  thanks for your comments

Comment: as I said, @KalaiselvanA - my comment was **not** a criticism

Comment: @JaromandaX yep, I think we both understand it and are not criticising your comment ;-)

Comment: I don't really like the double equal or a ternary that returns an empty string but the returned value is not set anywhere

Comment: @klugjo "I don't like" is really not a technical reason. If you set any limitations - please explain why those exist.

Comment: The limitations are the limitations of writing proper JavaScript. Double equal when you are obviously comparing 2 booleans is a sign of poor code. Returning a empty string that is not used anywhere is also an obvious code smell. Please see my answer below for a clean JavaScript expression of the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [Object.seal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)

Though, you'll want to "deeply" seal the object:

```js
const sealDeep = obj => {
    const sealProps = o => {
        Object.values(o).forEach(value => {
            if (typeof value === 'object') {
                sealProps(value);
                Object.seal(value);
            }
        });
    };
    sealProps(obj);
    Object.seal(obj);
};

var x = {
    hello: {
        world: {
            foo: 1,
            bar: 2
        },
        bat: '3'
    },
    foo2: 4
};
sealDeep(x);
console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
x.newthing = 999;
x.hello.newthing = 999;
x.hello.world.newthing = 999;
x.hello.world.foo = 999;
console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
```

Comment: Interesting solution but far from the one liner I was looking for. This will never pass code review ;)

Comment: Sneak in the sealDeep function. After that it's a one liner

Comment: My app is in the tens of thousands of lines of code. The potential for nasty side effects here is way too high.

Comment: I was kidding, though adding those 12 lines for `sealDeep` wouldn't have any side effects unless you **use** the function :p

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, and settled for this non-lodash solution

```
function overridePropertyByJsonPath(obj, thePath, value) {
  const path = thePath.split('.');
  let i
  for (i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
    const val = obj[path[i]]
    if (val === undefined) {
      return
    }
    obj = val
  }
  if (obj[path[i]] === undefined) {
    return
  }
  obj[path[i]] = value;
}
```

It passes all these tests I came up with

```
describe("Key overriding should allow ", () => {
  it("override shallow key", () => {
    const o = { a1: true }
    overridePropertyByJsonPath(o, "a1", false)
    expect(o["a1"]).toEqual(false)
  })
  it("no extra key with non-empty object", () => {
    const o = { a1: true }
    overridePropertyByJsonPath(o, "a2", false)
    expect(o["a2"]).toBeUndefined()
  })

  it("no extra keys with empty object", () => {
    const o = {}
    overridePropertyByJsonPath(o, "not_there_to_begin_with", true)
    expect(o["not_there_to_begin_with"]).toBeUndefined()
  })
  it("no extra keys in override (deep)", () => {
    const o = { a: { b: true } }
    overridePropertyByJsonPath(o, "a.b.not_there_to_begin_with", true)
    expect(o["a"]["b"]["not_there_to_begin_with"]).toBeUndefined()
  })
  it("no extra keys in override (too deep)", () => {
    const o = { a: { b: true } }
    overridePropertyByJsonPath(o, "a.b.c.not_there_to_begin_with", true)
    expect(o["a"]["b"]["c"]).toBeUndefined()
  })
  it("override deep key", () => {
    const o = { a: { b: true } }
    overridePropertyByJsonPath(o, "a.b", false)
    expect(o["a"]["b"]).toEqual(false)
  })
  it("override deep key with array value", () => {
    const o = { a: { b: [1] } }
    overridePropertyByJsonPath(o, "a.b", [2])
    expect(o["a"]["b"]).toContain(2)
    expect(o["a"]["b"].length).toEqual(1)
  })
  it("override deep key with object value", () => {
    const o = { a: { b: {} } }
    overridePropertyByJsonPath(o, "a.b", { "x": true })
    expect(o["a"]["b"]["x"]).toEqual(true)
  })

})
```